# Download TFS Process template

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I Create online account and create customized process Template and currently in install TFS in Local Server i need to copy my Process Template to the new server

i did not found download process Template any where

Answer (score 2):

There currently is none. You can use the REST api to extract the process template, but there is no way to "port" these to the "old-style" xml process templates for TFS.